# create login page that have 2 buttons, "Admin" and "Member" button

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

I am new in asp.net 4.0.
I want to create login page that have 2 buttons, "Admin" and "Member" button.
I want to ask, how can I connect to database both this button?

Comment: Could you provide more details, what do you mean precisely when wrote `connect to database`?

Comment: there was this spell at Hogwarts "Accio Database!". Pal, please take some time to frame your question.

Comment: How to provide a login page for different users?  UserName|Password|UserType
  mutu  |mutu    |Admin
   raja |rajaa   |User                                              They all must in a same login page..

Answer (score 0):

use Begin form like this

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("PostLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```